# Entity Framework Association Table Does Not Work Right

Tags: entity-framework

I have the `MenuItems` and `OptionContainers` SQL tables. And I am using the `MenuItem_OptionContainer` association table for representing the many-to-many relationship between the two. Because I am using fields other than just the foreign keys, Entity Framework creates the association table rather than representing the foreign keys as navigation properties.

[image]

The problem is that, when I use the code snippet below:

```
MenuItem_OptionContainer moc = new MenuItem_OptionContainer();
moc.OptionContainer = oc;
menuItem.MenuItem_OptionContainer.Add(moc);
```

and persist the `menuItem`, `OptionContainers` that have the same `name` and `typeId` data are only inserted as a single record into the `MenuItem_OptionContainer`table.

There are 400 OptionContainers in 20 MenuItems. So, I would expect the association table MenuItem_OptionContainer to contain 400 records that map these. But I see 380 records and the missing records are the ones that correspond to OptionItems having the same fields except the primary key.

Why is that and how can I make it right?

Comment: Can you please tell us what didn't work clearly? Do you mean that the MenuItem instance doesn't inserted? Or it is that OptionContainer instance is inserted many times even if they have same name and typeId?

Comment: @CodeNotFound There are 400 OptionContainers in 20 MenuItems. So, I would expect the association table MenuItem_OptionContainer to contain 400 records that map these. But I see 380 records and the missing records are the ones that correspond to OptionItems having the same fields except the primary key.

Comment: The code you show may create an existing combination. This may pass without saving and without exceptions, so you don't notice nothing happened.